# Can I use a standard on-off switch for lights on a magnetic low voltage transformer?

Tags: wiring, lighting

My closet has two magnetic low-voltage halogen fixtures and a regular halogen fixture wired to a pair of Lutron Maestro dimmers. The full-voltage halogen fixture has stopped working, and I measure about 96 volts AC from the bulb contacts when it's on. I am blaming the switches, which have been in place about fourteen years. 
Can I replace them with regular three-way switches? I always want full brightness in the closet anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plain old mechanical switches are fine

Dimmers do funny things to the mains, so they are only compatible with what they say on the tin.  Plain old mechanical switches don't do funny things to the mains, they just turn them on and off.  So, a mechanical switch will work with any load up to its rating.